# What is the difference between USING A PROXY and TUNNELING THROUGH A PROXY

Tags: php, c, curl, libcurl

Is there any difference between USING A PROXY and TUNNELING THROUGH A PROXY

what effect does tunneling through a proxy has on the request, to be precise on Curl request

```
    $ch = curl_init();        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);            
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);
    if($use_tunnel == true){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);                
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '180.180.94.251');                
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '8080'); 
    }          
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);           
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE,CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,180);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,7200);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

does it make a special difference or make the request more anonymous.

please i need a more technical explanation, no matter how technical it is, please give me deep explanation

Comment: @Dharman kindly give a more technical details to your above comment or better still provide a link to an article that explain it more and detailed.

Comment: My comment was made up of links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the client wants to send a normal GET.

"tunneling through" means issuing a `CONNECT` request to the proxy, which sets up a tunnel to the target host, and then the client sends the GET request through that tunnel to the target. This is typically how clients do HTTPS over proxies to maintain peer to peer privacy and security.

When "just using" a proxy, the client sends the GET request to the proxy, which then under the hood contacts the remote host and performs the GET and returns the response back. In this setup, the client can take advantage of caching etc in the proxy but the proxy will also be able to spy on the traffic between the client and the remote host.